# Removing entities from another entity but not from database

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa

I have two entities: Player and Team:

`Player`:

```
@Data
@Entity
public class Player {
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String username;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "team")
    @JsonIgnore
    private Team team;
}
```

`Team`:

```
@Entity
@Data
public class Team {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private User captain;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<User> players;
}
```

`TeamRepository`:

```
@Repository
public interface TeamRepository extends JpaRepository<Team, Long> {
}
```

I want to delete the whole Team from database using `delete()` method from JPA. Unfortunately when I do so, all Players are also deleted from my database. I only want to detach them from the Team.

Adding `cascade = CascadeType.ALL/DELETE` to `Team` and calling `delete()` method results in `User` entities deletion from database, and that's what I don't want to happen.

Adding `cascade = CascadeType.DETACH` to `Team` and calling `delete()` throws me a

```
java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`32308008_localdb`.`users`, CONSTRAINT `FKhn2tnbh9fqjqeuv8ehw5ple7a` FOREIGN KEY (`team_id`) REFERENCES `team` (`id`))
```

exception and I have no idea why.

If someone have an idea how to delete Team entity and detach User from context but not from database I would be VERY thankful!

Comment: You're using bi-directional relationship. Remove team from Player. I think it will work

Comment: Secondly, use `FetchType.LAZY`. EAGER causes performance issues.

Comment: @TayyabRazaq So there's no other way than removing Team from Player?

Comment: If you remove the team entity from the user entity and that user is the captain, you will generate a data inconsistency.

I would update the team entity with the new captain in case the captain is the user you want to unlink from the team and so that the users are not removed from the database I would add to the player annotation "@OneToMany (orphanRemoval = false,. .. "

As Tayyab Razaq indicates, he would also use the Lazy relationship.